# theme('table'...) function doesn't print the table header

Tags: theming

I need to generate a table using `theme('table',array('headers'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));`

The table is printed but with no header. This is the code: I don't see any error nor missing part for the theme function

> ```
>     $header = array(
>     // creating array that contains data from first cell
>     array('data' => t('Header cell1')), 
>     // second cell
>     array('data' => t('Header cell2')), 
>     // and third cell
>     array('data' => t('Header cell3'))
>   );
>   // creating first row
>   $rows[] = array(
>     // output of first cell in 1 row
>     array('data' => t('Row 1 – Cell 1')),
>     // second cell
>     array('data' => t('Row 1 – Cell 2')),
>     // third cell
>     array('data' => t('Row 1 – Cell 3')) 
>   );
>   //second row output
>   $rows[] = array(
>     array('data' => t('Row 2 – Cell 1')),
>     array('data' => t('Row 2 – Cell 2')),
>     array('data' => t('Row 2 – Cell 3'))
>   );
>
>   echo theme('table',array('headers'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `theme('table',array('headers' => $header,'rows' => $rows))`, while you should be using `theme('table',array('header' => $header,'rows' => $rows))`. [theme_table()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) looks for a property called *header*, not *headers*.

> #### Parameters
>
> **$variables**: An associative array containing:
>
> - **header**: An array containing the table headers. Each element of the array can be either a localized string or an associative array with the following keys:
>
>   - **"data"**: The localized title of the table column.
>   - **"field"**: The database field represented in the table column (required if user is to be able to sort on this column).
>   - **"sort"**: A default sort order for this column ("asc" or "desc").
>   - Any HTML attributes, such as "colspan", to apply to the column header cell.
> - **rows**: An array of table rows. Every row is an array of cells, or an associative array with the following keys:
>
>   - **"data"**: an array of cells
>   - Any HTML attributes, such as "class", to apply to the table row.
>   - **"no_striping"**: a boolean indicating that the row should receive no 'even / odd' styling. Defaults to FALSE.
>
> Each cell can be either a string or an associative array with the following keys:
>
> - **"data"**: The string to display in the table cell.
> - **"header"**: Indicates this cell is a header.
> - Any HTML attributes, such as "colspan", to apply to the table cell.